# Calculating position of element in fixed point for TFT drawing

Tags: c, microcontroller, fixed-point

I'm currently writing the UI for a small uC project. Having some trouble with the calculating the position of a vertical line. The idea is to move the red line along the x - axis towards the end of the rectangle.

The value that is being incremented with an endless rotary encoder and has a range of 0 to 800 with increments of 1. Left side of the rectangle is the beginning of the x - axis aswell with x = 0. The range 0 - 800 represents 0 - 100.00 in Q13.3 fixed point notation with the data type being uint16_t.

The rectangle is currently 300pixel wide, i'm flexible with that but it shouldn't be less than 240pixel. Line is 1pixel wide.

The catch is, that due to performance limitations i can only use fixed point math, there should be no access to the floating point unit at all.

[image]

What i'm currently doing is having a counter that increments with every click of the encoder. sth. like:

```
        if(direction) counter++;        //Running forwards
        if(!direction) counter--;       //Running backwards
        if((counter % 8 ) == 0){
            if(direction) line.x += 3;
            if(!direction) line.x -= 3;
        }
```

which is less than optimal since the spacing is 3 pixel.

Ideally if float calculation was an option i would simply increment the counter with 0.375

Appreciate any advice on this issue.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the position of the counter in terms of `0 ... 800` and scale it down to `0 ... width`?

I.e. multiply the value of counter by `width` and *then* do an integer division by `max` where max is the max of your logical range.

```
uint16_t scale(uint16_t value, uint16_t logical_max, uint16_t physical_max)
{
   uint32_t val = value * physical_max; // use a wider type to cope with overflow
   return (uint16_t) ((val / logical_max) & 0xFFFFU);
}
```

Comment: This not the answer. It is good on decent processors and microcontrollers. But it is useless on tiny 8 bits machines with no hardware multiplication or division. Those operations on such s small micros are extremely expensive (tens or hundreds of instructions)

Comment: @P__J__ I kind of assumed decent integer math here, yes. So I did the simplest thing that could possibly work and also happens to be flexible w.r.t. ratios. There again we have  a `uint16_t` data type to work with, and the mention of a floating point unit so...

Answer (score 1):

on very small misros you need to do some tricks:

```
uint8_t result;
static uint8_t counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

void handleEncoderTickUp(void)
{   
    if(++counter1 == 2) {result++; counter1 = 0;}
    if(++counter2 == 3) {result +=2; counter2 = 0;}
}
```

Very similar to to count down

Comment: This also won't work very well if your counter is meant to go all the way to `800`.

Comment: encoders do not have counters only signals - and we can detect the direction and the tick. Simple micros do not have advanced timers with hardware encoder modes

Comment: Sure, and please do correct me if I am wrong, but as I understand it you must somehow be able to represent the *full* range of the counter because you have to be able to manipulate the position of the line from all the way to the left to all the way to the right (i.e. somebody turning the dial all the way up)... A `uint8_t` won't cover it, as it is simply not big enough...

Comment: Currently using ESP32-WROVER which has 2 low power xtensa 32-bit lx6 micros, can't use the fpu due to the non-ui-core doing quite some heavy dsp and accessing it from 2 different cores has a big performance impact. nonetheless i didn't hear any audio dropouts/glitches while incrementing the counter using @user268396 's answer

Comment: @P.Dias ESP32 is not small uC as you mentioned in your question. Muticore hundreds of MHz uC. You can do whatever is convenient for you.

Comment: @P__J__ it's the "smallest" i have worked with so far. Guess there are plenty smaller uC's on the market. Sorry for misphrasing the question. Appreciate your input nonetheless.